# How to animate with 'CADdisplaylink' (won't animate)

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am trying to animate my label called "Miles" with CADdisplaylink, even tho I don't receive any errors, the animation won't display correctly at the time I tap my UIButton. I tried fixing it myself, but I don't really know where the error is.

Tried moving my CADdisplaylink code inside the viewDidLoad, but this meant it would instantly start the animation (I don't know if that logic is really correct). So, changed it to my UIButton action code, so when it is pressed it'll execute the animation. It would only add up the 'endValue = self.myCar.miles! + 10' and then crash without letting me press anything else.

This is before the viewDidLoad

```
@IBOutlet var labelMiles: UILabel!
let animationDuration = 1.5
    let animationStartDate = Date()
```

this is after viewDidLoad and other code that has no relation with the animation.

```
@IBAction func accelerateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //        CAD display here; para animacion de MILES
        let cadDisplay = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(accelerateButton(_:)))
        cadDisplay.add(to: .main, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)

        guard let startValue = self.myCar.miles else { return () }
//        myCar.addMiles(addToMiles: 10.0)
        let endValue = self.myCar.miles! + 10
        let now = Date()
        let elapsedTime = now.timeIntervalSince(animationStartDate)
        if elapsedTime  > animationDuration {
            self.labelMiles.text = "\(endValue)"
        } else {
            let percentage = elapsedTime / animationDuration
            let value = percentage * (endValue - startValue)
            self.labelMiles.text = "\(value)"
        }

        /*myCar.acceletate()
            updateView()*/
    }
```

"accelerteButton" should trigger an animation that counts from the 'startValue', [which is a default value I have determined inside the viewDidLoad with other values, example:]

```
myCar = Car(miles: 12000.50, tires: 4, model: "SUV Santa Fe", age: 2019, companyName: "Hyundai", color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.05882352963, green: 0.180392161, blue: 0.2470588237, alpha: 1), imageName: UIImage(named: "Hyundai.jpg"))
        myGarage.append(myCar)
```

to the 'endValue', which should just add 10.0 (as it it a Double).
Is there any error I am missing?

Comment: You're crashing because your `accelerateButton` creates a display link that calls `accelerateButton`. So you're just calling yourself recursively over and over until you get (wait for it) a stack overflow.

Comment: Can you explain why you are using DisplayLink in the first place. It's a pretty clumsy way to do animation and is rarely needed.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply , because It is the only way I learned how to animate a label, I really don't know any other way (yet) :/
About the response above, should I call the display link with another name and then create a function for it INSIDE the button?

Comment: Fair enough, thanks alot Matt!!